# iOS Verify App Installation success

Tags: ios

I want to create a cross promotion on my app, and give bonus stuff after user installs and runs my other applications. Is there any easy way to do this? I have looked at the iOS8 plugins functions, but this also needs to work on iOS7. Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like Avocarrot will help you do something like this, it enables cross app sponsering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work across multiple devices I'd probably say you'd need to implement a webservice that stores the users information such as a unique identifier for that user (Not device) so something like the users username and update it with the new app that they have just downloaded and installed and signed in using that username.

If this is just on a per device basis you could probably do it using Custom URL Schemes. Each of your apps would have a Custom URL Scheme and when the user opens the app you can do a check to see if any of the other Custom URL Schemes are installed on that device by using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:]` and if this returns true then that app is installed.

Here's the Apple Documentation for [Inter-App Communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)

Comment: Most of my users do not log in, so for me to verify via user ID would not be viable. Is there any unique ID i can use per device?

Comment: Well if it's a per device basis there is no point in doing it with a webserver you might as well use the Custom URL Schemes. The idea of the username as a unique identifier is that the user can then use it with other devices so it will not change across devices whereas a unique ID for a device will change per device. So for you I'd say go via the Custom URL Scheme route.

Answer (score 3):

Use custom URL schemes in both your apps and after that just check if the iOS system has the URL scheme registered. If so, then the user had installed the other app.

Here's an [example](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html) on how to do it.